Equivalent definitions of a wavelet
Im new in the field of wavelet theory. I see two different notations in the literature about the definition of wavelets:
First one
A wavelet is a function $\psi \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ which satisfies the condition
$$
C_{\psi} \equiv \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{|\hat{\psi}(\omega)|^2}{|\omega|} \, d\omega < \infty,
$$
where $\hat{\psi}(\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of $\psi(t)$.
Second one
Let $\psi \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.
For $j, k \in \mathbb{Z}$, define the function $\psi_{j,k}$ by
$$
\psi_{j,k}(x) := 2^{j/2} \psi(2^j x - k), \quad x \in \mathbb{R}.
$$
The function $\psi$ is called a wavelet if the functions $\{\psi_{j,k}\}_{j,k \in \mathbb{Z}}$ form an orthonormal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.
I know that
$$
(\hat{\psi}_{j,k})(\omega) = 2^{-j/2} \hat{\psi}(2^{-j} \omega) e^{-i 2^{-j} k \omega}.
$$
Furthermore I thought Parseval would be useful. But I am quite stuck.
Can some give a proof why  these two definitions are equivalent. Many thanks in advance!

I am quite sure that the two are not equivalent. But condition 2 implies condition 1, if I remember correctly. This should be contained for instance in the book by Daubechies.

For instance, if the first condition holds for $\psi$, then also for $c \psi$ for any c. For the second condition, this is not true.

The first is for CWT, the second a special case of the DWT, so the definitions concern slightly different topics, and thus can not be equivalent.
In-between you have wavelet frames and biorthogonal wavelet transforms, where the generating functions have still different characterizations.
